# trying to scale raw input from touchscreen but touchcollection is read-only

Tags: c#, android, xna, touch, monogame

So I was implementing code to handle phones of varying resolutions using the article listed below.  In the article he shows how to easily scale a gesture so that input as well as graphics work properly at any resolution.  Problem is that I use raw input and when i went to modify the place where the touch collection is read its telling me its read only, so i can read in and modify the input, but i can't put it back in the list.  Any ideas on an easy way around this?

code i was fooling around with looks as follows

```
        TouchState = TouchPanel.GetState();

        foreach (TouchLocation location in TouchState)
        {
            Vector2 NewPosition = Vector2.Transform(location.Position - ScreenManager.InputTranslate, ScreenManager.InputScale);
            TouchLocation NewTL = new TouchLocation(location.Id, location.State, NewPosition);
            TouchState.Remove(location); //errors on this line as well as the add below
            TouchState.Add(NewTL);

        }
```

http://infinitespace-studios.co.uk/2012/08/06/handling-multiple-screen-resolutions-in-monogame-for-android-part-2/#comment-69

Comment: Keep a clone of the information you need from the TouchState and scale your clone. The library isn't going to let you tell it whats going on physically, which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  This got me on the right track.  Instead of using a touchcollection i ended up using a list of touchlocations, which is essentially what a touchcolllection is.  Thanks again!